# Calling information from one table based on many-to-many table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, many-to-many

I'm a bit stuck on using the INNER JOIN concept with mySQL & PHP to call information from two tables. I would consider myself an upper-level beginner in PHP & mySQL, using Dreamweaver to lean on from time to time as well.

What I have is a "Accounts" table with a primary key `account_id` which is stored to a session when a user is logged in. I have a m2m table which stores `account_id` and it's `production_id`. And lastly I have a `Productions` table with a primary key of (you guessed it) `production_id`. What I'm trying to do is have it look up all the productions a user is assigned to (via the m2m table) and pull the details for those specific productions, from the productions table itself. I'm assuming using INNER JOIN would be the way to go about this?

Here's what I was trying to execute (note that "sessionaccountid" is setup on Dreamweaver's end to pull the session data already).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Productions
JOIN  Accounts Productions Junction on account_id = sessionaccountid
```

Unfortunately, this is turning up a Not unique table error in mySQL. Any guidance on getting this to lock in right would be appreciated! And of course if you could also explain what I did wrong/how your suggestion makes more sense, so I can write it down for myself, that would also be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is your current query doesn't follow nether implicit nor explicit `JOIN` syntax and therefore is incorrect.

Use explicit ANSI `JOIN` syntax and specify how your tables are related in your query

```sql
SELECT a.account_id, a.account_name, p.production_id, p.production_name 
  FROM Junction j JOIN Accounts a
    ON j.account_id = a.account_id JOIN Productions p
    ON j.production_id = p.production_id
 WHERE j.account_id = ?
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b9f34/4)** demo